# Login by pass using C#.net program

Tags: c#, http, authentication, post

My goal is to provide a link to customer, when a customer clicks the link he/she should be automatically logged in to this new site(external website not controlled by our company) using their logged in AD credentials. 
FYI, the logged in credentials match the login name on this external website and the password will be the same for all. So, I can safely hardcode the password in my program.

Now what I was thinking was to write a C# program that will complete the authentication process for the External website and returns back the page that is received after login.

My analysis:-

1) When I first visit the page `http://website2/default.aspx`, it returns back a login page  with username, password and submit button.

I also noticed that it is returning a session id.
    ***ASP.NET_SessionId=i0j3d155mxxkuyr3fedp00yf***.

2) Later, when I enter username, password and  click the submit button. 
It is creating a query string as such 
***user=adf&password=adsf&buttonName=Login+%21***

I think it is using an HTTP Post call.

Can you please help me this!!!! Please, if possible provide me with a code that I can refer to and make changes to acheive this.....
Thanks a lot for looking....Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this since there is no way to retrieve a password from AD.  The only way this would be possible is if there was a trust relationship between the external site and yours and it sounds like this is not the case (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

You'll need to have the user manually enter authentication and marshal that information to the external site, which is really no better than just having the user authenticate directly to the external site.

On a side note, it's rarely the case where you can safely hardcode a password in a program. Just sayin. Also, if you're getting a query string that you can see in the browser's address bar then it's not using POST, it's using GET.